# How do I fix browser icon that remains just like Internet Explorer 8 after installing 9?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I installed Internet Explorer (IE) 9 on my Windows 7 32 bit OS, the installation was successful, but the icon remain same as that of IE 8.  How do I fix this?

Comment: not sure why it didn't update, but I've found when I manually update icons the change sometimes doesn't appear until after I restart explorer or reboot. Try a reboot and if that doesn't work (but everything else seems to work) you could always change it manually.

Comment: You are lucky: I prefer the old IE8 icon to the new one, and would have appreciated to keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is with a desktop icon, it is easy enough to fix, and it is not worthwhile to trace such a glitch in the installation :

Right-click the icon, select Properties and then click Change icon. The IE9 icon is probably the first one, so click on it and then on OK.

Answer (score 1):

If restart doesnt help, then you can try to recover the Icon Cache of Win 7
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-rebuild-the-icon-cache-in-windows-vista/

Greetings,

mitsosc

Answer (score -1):

right click on the taskbar icon , unpin the IE 9.
click windows button , search for internet Explorer , now right click icon and click , pin to task bar . Done

Comment: That presumes Internet Explorer found is IE8...